# Is there a way to use my Access accdb or accde file (Created on the desktop) on an ipad?

Tags: ms-access

It would need to be able to read [AND write]***redacted. I only need it to read info. I can store the database either on the network or on the cloud (Microsoft Azure). Is there an app or another way to be able to use my split accdb or accde file on the ipad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know - NO.

On iMac you can use emulator software, but on iPad there is no such possibility.